# parse json from html request

Tags: javascript, json

I'm facing `origin is not allowed b access-control-allow-origin` error, when I want to get JSON data through javascript request, but when I'm typing the url of the JSON data on my browser I can read the data successfully.

Is there a way to get JSON data from the browser page, in a way or another?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067509/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin is this helpful? (hint: yes it is!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)